# tag for a hyphened word in Ruby

Tags: rubygems

I am new at the age of 76. I look up the web and cannot find a simple answer to this simple question: I just want to know **how to write a hyphenated word e.g. off-campus in Ruby**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Ruby.

Your question is a little confusing, because it's not clear what you mean by "write a hypenated word in Ruby"

If you want Ruby to *output* a hyphenated word, you should have no problem, because both of these will output fine:

```
puts "highly-efficient is sometimes hyphenated"
puts "highly efficient is also sometimes not hyphenated"
```

But I have a feeling your real issue is trying to use a hyphenated word in the ruby language.  Presumably this would be as a variable (or class/module/..) name, since there are no keywords or other possible hyphenated words in the Ruby language.  Names of variables, classes, etc.. are called 'identifiers'

The reality is that you cannot use hyphenated words as variable names in Ruby, and the reason is simple:

```
highly = 42
efficient = 10
puts highly-efficient
# This will output 32, which is 42-10
```

This can be further seen by looking at the definition of Identifiers in the ruby syntax:

[Ruby Syntax for Identifiers](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#ident)

> "Ruby identifiers are consist of alphabets, decimal digits, and the
> underscore character, and begin with a alphabets(including
> underscore). There are no restrictions on the lengths of Ruby
> identifiers."

Consider using either camelCase or snake_case for multi-word identifiers, such as "off_campus" or "offCampus".

Comment: If this answer is correct in guessing what your problem is, please select it and consider editing your question to be more clear about what you were looking for, something like "how to have a hyphenated variable in ruby"